# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 AMD GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, 17.04, amdgpu

My laptop has an AMD Radeon R5 M335 4GB DDR3L GPU which is currently disabled from the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT "radeon.modeset=0 amdgpu.runpm=0" because it was causing constant crashes right after loggin in.

I would like to know if there's any good drivers for my GPU?
I have tried AMDGPU-PRO but that too causes constant crashes because my GPU wasn't supported (it wasn't on the list of supported GPU(s))

So, is there any other good drivers that support AMD Radeon R5 M335?
The laptop I'm using is a Dell Inspiron 14 5459, core i7, 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD, etc~

Thanks! :)

Comment: Note: you may wish to check out these video drivers... https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers look at the bottom of the instructions for how to add the PPA.

Comment: I'm sure that you've probably checked http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Comment: I don't think you will find any good ones. I have a Radeon R5 M330 (so same GPU series) and I tried using the `padoka` PPA (it is like `oibaf` but newer and less stable, however I never noticed any crashes) and it is as bad as the default `radeon`. I tried AMDGPU-PRO and the result is the very famous login loop.